# JEditorPane - setText from ArrayList<String> contents?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jeditorpane

I have read through the JEditorPane Docs, from what I can understand you simply need to editorpane.setText(String value); however I am quite new to java and this solution does not work with my code. I think I am missing something obvious but completely out of ideas.

I have created a new tab with this class that extends JEditorPane, this class is designed to open the contents of the file, put them on an array, reverse the array (so latest entry is on the top) then display this list in the JEditorPane (using JeditorPane because I need to make the save url's into hyperlinks),

```
public class HistoryPane extends JEditorPane{

ArrayList<String> historyToSort = new ArrayList<String>();

public HistoryPane(){
    setEditable(false); 
    historySort();
}


public void historySort() {

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("BrowserHistory.txt")))
    {

        String currentLine;
        String newLine = new String("\n");

        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            historyToSort.add(currentLine + newLine);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    Collections.reverse(historyToSort);
    System.out.println(historyToSort);  
    }

{
}

private void displayHistory(){
    String sorted = historyToSort.toString();
*****   HistoryPane.setText(String sorted); <<<------ PROBLEM SYNTAX.*****

}
}
```

I have tried multiple different entries into the setText() parenthesis with no luck. What am I missing? Thank You.

NOTE:

This class won't compile because it is reliant on another class (I can't paste all of it) but this code sits within a tabbed pane created by my main class:

Error Message:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>     Syntax error on token "setText", Identifier expected after this token
>     Return type for the method is missing
>     This method requires a body instead of a semicolon

Comment: What doesn't work? What do you expect this code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Where do you call `setText()`?

Comment: Apologies, I expected the code to display my array(lines of history from file) on the screen in the editorpane. I call it at the very bottom "HistoryPane.setText(String sorted);" or so I thought .... I thought that would set the text displayed on JEditorPane. The problem is I get errors from the IDE that just wont accept the STRING and Value into setText() ... it just offers up suggestions none of which are valid.

Comment: The code doesn't even compile. Is that the problem? If so, Have you tried reading and understanding the error messages from the compiler? What do they say?

Comment: I have updated the question with the main-class section that creates this class (hence why it won't compile) the problem is i cant get the syntax right on "HistoryPane.setText(String sorted);" ... I assumed that would display the text from my array in the editor pane.... but it wont accept my wording.

Comment: A JEditorPane display HTML. So the string you use in the setText() method must be a string with properly formatted HTML. An Array is not a single string of HTML so this approach won't work. You need to convert the Array to a single String of HTML yourself.

Comment: You're trying to execute code that doesn't even compile. Go to Window - Show view - Other... - Problems in Eclipse, and fix every compilation error listed in this view before executing the program. To fix them, *read* the error message and try to understand it. If you're stuck, *post* the error message here. Error messages contain valuable information, and are intended to be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, despite the fact that you haven't read the error message, it seems you're really a newbie, so I'll help.

```
HistoryPane.setText(String sorted);
```

The above isn't valid Java. A method invocation takes a list of arguments, without a type.

```
HistoryPane.setText(sorted);
```

Now that is a valid method invocation. But it tries to invoke a *static* method called `setText()` of the *class* HistoryPane. What you want is to invoke the *instance* method `setText()` on the current *object*. So the valid syntax is

```
this.setText(sorted);
```

or simply

```
setText(sorted);
```

That should solve this particular compilation error. Don't try to run your app before every compilation error, listed in the Problems view of Eclipse, is fixed.

Note that the above line won't do what you want it to do, but I'll let you investigate what you should do instead.

My advice: don't try using Swing, which is quite a complex beast, if you don't even know how to call a method yet. Start with very simple Java exercises, not involving any GUI, until you're familiar with the Java syntax, and understand how to read, understand and fix basic compilation problems.

Comment: Thank You, I was confusing myself with the wording of JEditorPane which in combination with lack of experience ended up as you said. Also I noticed I hadn't even called the method that was not working. I missed out a line. Thank You for your patience.